# ant file for TeX compilation

Tags: java, tex, ant

Here is an ant script for generating TeX code and documentation for one LaTeX class and one LaTeX package. It is my first larger ant script: I welcome suggestions for improvements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project name="customer TeX code" default="main">
<description>Buildscript for the LaTeX classes and packages</description>

<property name="foo" value="foo" />
<property name="bar" value="bar" />

<!-- target: init -->
<target name="init" description="initialize properties">
    <condition property="foo.uptodate">
        <and>
            <available file="${foo}.cls" />
            <available file="${foo}.drv" />
            <available file="${foo}.pdf" />
            <uptodate property="foo.cls.uptodate" targetfile="${foo}.cls">
                <srcfiles file="${foo}.dtx" />
                <srcfiles file="${foo}.ins" />
            </uptodate>
            <uptodate property="foo.drv.uptodate" targetfile="${foo}.drv">
                <srcfiles file="${foo}.dtx" />
                <srcfiles file="${foo}.ins" />
            </uptodate>
            <uptodate property="foo.pdf.uptodate" targetfile="${foo}.pdf">
                <srcfiles file="${foo}.dtx" />
                <srcfiles file="${foo}.ins" />
            </uptodate>
        </and>
    </condition>
    <condition property="bar.uptodate">
        <and>
            <available file="${bar}.sty" />
            <available file="${bar}.drv" />
            <available file="${bar}.pdf" />
            <uptodate property="bar.sty.uptodate" targetfile="${bar}.sty">
                <srcfiles file="${bar}.dtx" />
                <srcfiles file="${bar}.ins" />
            </uptodate>
            <uptodate property="bar.drv.uptodate" targetfile="${bar}.drv">
                <srcfiles file="${bar}.dtx" />
                <srcfiles file="${bar}.ins" />
            </uptodate>
            <uptodate property="bar.pdf.uptodate" targetfile="${bar}.pdf">
                <srcfiles file="${bar}.dtx" />
                <srcfiles file="${bar}.ins" />
            </uptodate>
        </and>
    </condition>
</target>

<!-- target: foo -->
<target name="foo" unless="foo.uptodate" depends="init" description="builds all files for the foo class">
    <exec executable="latex" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${foo}.ins" />
    </exec>
    <exec executable="lualatex" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-draftmode" />
        <arg value="${foo}.drv" />
    </exec>
    <parallel>
        <exec executable="makeindex" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-s" />
            <arg value="gind.ist" />
            <arg value="-t" />
            <arg value="${foo}.ind.ilg" />
            <arg value="${foo}.idx" />
        </exec>
        <exec executable="makeindex" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-s" />
            <arg value="gglo.ist" />
            <arg value="-t" />
            <arg value="${foo}.gls.ilg" />
            <arg value="-o" />
            <arg value="${foo}.gls" />
            <arg value="${foo}.glo" />
        </exec>
    </parallel>
    <exec executable="lualatex" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-draftmode" />
        <arg value="${foo}.drv" />
    </exec>
    <exec executable="lualatex" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${foo}.drv" />
    </exec>
</target>

<!-- target: bar -->
<target name="bar" unless="bar.uptodate" depends="init" description="builds all files for the bar package">
    <exec executable="latex" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${bar}.ins" />
    </exec>
    <exec executable="lualatex" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-draftmode" />
        <arg value="${bar}.drv" />
    </exec>
    <parallel>
        <exec executable="makeindex" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-s" />
            <arg value="gind.ist" />
            <arg value="-t" />
            <arg value="${bar}.ind.ilg" />
            <arg value="${bar}.idx" />
        </exec>
        <exec executable="makeindex" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-s" />
            <arg value="gglo.ist" />
            <arg value="-t" />
            <arg value="${bar}.gls.ilg" />
            <arg value="-o" />
            <arg value="${bar}.gls" />
            <arg value="${bar}.glo" />
        </exec>
    </parallel>
    <exec executable="lualatex" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-draftmode" />
        <arg value="${bar}.drv" />
    </exec>
    <exec executable="lualatex" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${bar}.drv" />
    </exec>
</target>

<!-- target: main -->
<target name="main" depends="foo, bar" description="default target" />
</project>
```

Comment: Can’t comment specifically on the ant file but it seems like a lot of effort. Are you aware of the existence of `latexmk` which ships with all modern TeX distributions and which is a versatile build tool for TeX (requiring in most cases *zero* configuration)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yes. But I need it on Windows, MacOS and Linux. And I fear that the configuration latexmk needs for _this_ build process and the dependencies is also quite non-trivial. And I wanted to learn ant. `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bar` and `foo` targets (as well as the conditions on `foo.uptodate` and `bar.uptodate`) seems really similar to each other. I'd try to remove this duplication with a [`presetdef`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/presetdef.html) or a [`macrodef`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html)

*Reply for the edit*:

Nice to see that the `macrodef` works :-). A few other ideas:

1. ```
   <attribute name="basename" default="unknown" />
   ```

   Are you sure that you need the `default` attribute here? The `macrodef` documentation says the following:

   > The attributes will be required attributes unless a default value has been set.
2. I'd create a list for

   ```
   <srcfiles file="@{basename}.dtx" />
   <srcfiles file="@{basename}.ins" />
   ```

   Here is an example: [Ant: using Filelist as Fileset in Uptodate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4565492/843804)
3. After this I guess the three `uptodate` tag could be replaced with only one which uses a composite or a chained mapper but I'm not too familiar with these.

Comment: Thanks; I've added a new version with `macrodef` to the question.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Thanks for the feedback! I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question with a new version with `union` and `srcresources`. That seems to be an area that's severly underdocumented in the online manual. `:-(`